# Standard algorithm which output or traverse all pair combination of a set?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Is there a standard algorithm which output all pair combination of a set (e.g. `std::set`), or run an operation for such pair combination and write results as another collection, like `std::transform` for combination of 2 out of N?

The goal is that we don't need to write double loop or recursion ourselves. Or reduce that work as much as possible, with help of existing library etc.

To be clear, if we have a set {1, 2, 3}, the pair combination would be:

```
[1,2]
[1,3]
[2,3]
```

Comment: I don't think there is something out of the box

Comment: Removed "other languages, that would be "too broad". Just STL / C++ would suffice.

Comment: Sorry Bill your question isn't clear to me... do you want to find the intersection of two sets? if so std::set_intersection may be what you're after

Comment: If by "standard algorithm" you mean something from `<algorithm>` supplied with the standard library, no, there isn't.

Comment: Eh, "No" looks is a pretty valid answer to me... But please include version info.

Comment: When I add Java tag, it automatically goes to 1st position. Is it possible to avoid Java being 1st tag please?

Comment: Yes, you can remove it, as it will be too broad if you include it. Note that your original Q seems a bit strange to me. You would not switch runtime just for this feature, would you? I really don't see what's wrong with a double loop neither.

Comment: @MattCoubrough, I've added an example. Hope it helps. Thx!^^

Comment: Ok, given your eg set_intersection isn't what you're after, but if you have to roll your own it shouldn't be tricky: just pick the first element from the set, create an ordered pair with the selected element and every remaining element, then pick the next element and repeat. I can't think off hand of a more efficient way to do it, and no recursion is necessary. just a nested loop.

Comment: I don't understand why someone down-voted my question. I can still ask it even if the answer is 'no', right? lol

Comment: You may have got the downvote due to the confusion over java v c++ or the slight ambiguity in the original post before you added the example?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a standard method, but here's a simple working example and I personally can't think of a more efficient method:

```
// set up some sample data:
std::set<int> myset;
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++ ) 
{
    myset.insert(i);
}

std::set<int>::iterator it;
std::set<int>::iterator it2;

for( it=myset.begin(); it != myset.end(); ++it) {

    int a = *it;
    it2 = std::set<int>::iterator(it);
    it2++;
    for(; it2 != myset.end(); it2++) {
        int b = *it2;
        std::cout << "[" << a << "," << b << "]";
    }
}
```

Which yields the output:

```
[0,1][0,2][0,3][0,4][1,2][1,3][1,4][2,3][2,4][3,4]
```

Of course you need to create std::pair<> of the two elements (or similar) and put 'em into an output set rather than just spit them out to the console.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This method worked for me. It's also easily templated to accept input from a forward iterator of any type. However, that will have to be left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't standard library algorithms for this but it's easy to write your own STL-like algorithms to do what you're asking.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

template <typename FwdIt, typename Fn>
void for_each_pair(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, Fn func)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        for (FwdIt next = first; ++next != last;) {
            func(*first, *next);
        }
    }
}

template <typename FwdIt, typename OutIt>
OutIt copy_pairs(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, OutIt dest)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        for (FwdIt next = first; ++next != last;) {
            *dest++ = std::make_pair(*first, *next);
        }
    }
    return dest;
}

template <typename FwdIt, typename OutIt, typename BinOp>
OutIt transform_pairs(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, OutIt dest, BinOp op)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        for (FwdIt next = first; ++next != last;) {
            *dest++ = op(*first, *next);
        }
    }
    return dest;
}

int main()
{
    std::set<int> seq{ 1, 2, 3 };

    for_each_pair(
        std::begin(seq), std::end(seq),
        [](int a, int b){ std::cout << '[' << a << ',' << b << "]\n"; }
    );

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec;
    copy_pairs(std::begin(seq), std::end(seq), std::back_inserter(vec));

    for (auto &pr : vec) {
        std::cout << '[' << pr.first << ',' << pr.second << "]\n";
    }

    std::vector<int> vec2;
    transform_pairs(std::begin(seq), std::end(seq), std::back_inserter(vec2), std::plus<int>());

    for (auto value : vec2) {
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Blastfurnace. Thanks a lot for the idea! Pls note we want "combination of 2 out of N", i.e. no repeat values in the pair. See the example in the Q.

Comment: @Bill: This code does reproduce the example output in your question. [See it here on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/3wNk29)